# Android Error parsing package - partial download

Tags: android, android-install-apk, android-internal-storage

I am trying to download and install an update to my android out outside the Google Play Store.
using this tutorial as a guide (http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-update-android-apk-outside-the-playstore/) I inserted code in my app to download the apk file for my app (that has the updates) from my google drive.

The app only downloads part of the file (maybe the first 14KB to 100KB).

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public class ApkUpdateTask extends AsyncTask <String,Void,Void>{
    private Context context;
    public void setContext(Context contextf){
        context = contextf;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            String PATH = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/";
            //String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File file = new File(PATH);
            //file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, "sonandso.apk");
            if(outputFile.exists()){
                outputFile.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            //intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath())), "blahblah.apk");
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/")), "blahblah.apk");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
            context.startActivity(intent);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UpdateAPP", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. I have made both signed and unsigned apks. Both fail to download the full app.
2. I have the api level of the apk set to the same api level of the device (in the gradle build file. I am using Android Studio). Android version is 5.1.1 (and it has to be because of the project).
3. I am calling the above listed code (that I put into a separate class file) from the Main Fragment. Should this be called from the main activity itself??
4. I am trying to write to the internal storage memory and not an external SD card. Could this be the issue? If so - how can I write it to the internal storage memory?
5. I have tried using "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()" for the path as well and that didn't work either. See #4 for questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have decided to put this on the shelf and look at using a google API based approach that I am still researching.